# C - scanf object's arguments

Tags: c, object, parameter-passing, scanf

I'm new in C. I'm trying to make an `addStudent()` function like this:

I'm currently stuck on 2 issues:

1. No matter what I have entered, the object's name, mid, and final are still empty or zero.
2. If I change the `name` parameter to `*name`, it only takes the first character. ie, if `"James"` is entered, it only takes "J".

UPDATE: I firstly thought it was scanf's problem, but even when I removed it and initialized the variables, the object std is still empty. I was still wondering what is the correct way to pass arguments to a new object, like this example.

```
void addStudent(struct Student array[SIZE], int *currentSize){
    char name[20];
    int mid, final;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Enter midterm grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &mid);
    printf("Enter final grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &final);
    struct Student std = {*name, mid, final};
    array[0] = std;
    ++*currentSize;
}
```

Student structure:

```
struct Student{
    char name[20];
    int midterm;
    int final;
};
```

---

FIXED:
If I directly passed the variables to scanf, everything works fine.

```
void addStudent(struct Student array[], int *currentSize){
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", array[*currentSize].name);
    printf("Enter midterm grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &array[*currentSize].midterm);
    printf("Enter final grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &array[*currentSize].final);
    
    ++*currentSize;
}
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `Student`?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include the Student constructor

Comment: You can't use ANY user-input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. The applies with particularity to the `scanf` family of functions.

Comment: You cannot initialize `std = {name, mid, final}` because on access `name` is converted to a pointer to the first element. It is not a string literal and is no longer an array. You need `struct Student std = {"", mid, final}; strcpy (std.name, name);`

Comment: Thank you so much, @David. This worked perfectly on my code. Could you explain what these lines do to my code? How come it also works with the mid and final as well? If I remove strcpy (std.name, name), mid and final would be zero.

Comment: You could "get away" with `scanf (" %19[^0-9\n]", name)` to handle whitespace in the name -- but only if your next input consumes leading whitespace (which all but `"%c"` and `"%[...]"` do)

Comment: @KhoaLe the `struct Student std = {"", mid, final};` declaration for `std` initializes `std.name` with the *String Literal* `""` (empty-string) to allow the initializer to work -- you can initialize a character array with a *String Literal* -- technically it initializes the first char to `0` and the rest are initialized to `0` by default -- [§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p19)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19)). Then `strcpy (std.name, name);` simply copies `name` to `std.name` completing filling `std` for you.

Comment: Your question says you have a problem with `scanf()` but you later say in the comment to Sourav's answer that the problem is with the initialization of the structure. - What now? And how do you have proof that the `scanf()`'s work correctly? There is no printing of them. Voted to close as needs more focus.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with 1. "*No matter what I have entered (in the scanf), the object's name, mid, and final are still empty or zero*" - Do you mean the objects inside of the function or the objects inside of the structure? --- 2. "*If I change the "name" parameter to "*name"*, ...". - Do you mean here the `scanf()` call or the initialization of the structure?

Answer (score 1):

`%s` format specifier with [`scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) reads space-delimited input. In other words, it cannot read a "complete" input which contains white-space.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.21.6.2

> *`s`*
>
> *Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters. [....]*

You should use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the input and then process it.

That said, changing the argument to `%s` to `*name` is not correct anyways, as it creates mismatch between the expected (pointer to character array) and the actual (character) - creating [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I don't even have a white-space in "name". I tried to scan the variables and print them out using printf; everything works fine. The problem happens when I pass them to the Student object.